# PHP $format not trimming after 30 days

Tags: php

I'm building a PHP countdown and I'm having a issue with my formatting, I need to add a 0 if it's less than 10 days and to remove that 0 if it's more than 9
`

```
    for($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++)
    {$interval = date_diff($future_date, $now);
    if($future_date < $now){
        // Open the first source image and add the text.
        $image = imagecreatefrompng('images/countdownBlank.png');
        // $text = $interval->format('SALE OVER');
        $font['size'] = 38;
        imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset-over'] , $font['y-offset-over'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
        ob_start();
        imagegif($image);
        $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
        $delays[]=$delay;
        $loops = 1;
        ob_end_clean();
        break;
    } else {
        // Open the first source image and add the text.
        $image = imagecreatefrompng('images/img_countdown_bg.png');
        //$text = $interval->format('0%a %H %I %S');
        //$text = $interval->format('0%a %H %I');
        $length = 2;
        $format = ($interval -> d < 10 ? '0' : null).'%a %H %I';
        $text = $interval -> format($format);
        imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
        ob_start();
        imagegif($image);
        $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
        $delays[]=$delay;
        $loops = 0;
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    $now->modify('+1 second');
}`
```

I can see that my date is being trimmed in the following code:

`$format = ($interval -> d < 10 ? '0' : null).'%a %H %I';
 $text = $interval -> format($format);`

And this is the end result:
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTNI5.png)

many thanks for the help

Comment: `str_pad($str, 2, '0');`

Comment: sorry for the trouble, but I'm a designer so I'm not sure where to put the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$format = ($interval -> d < 10 ? '0' : null).'%a %H %I';
```

to

```
$format = ($interval->days < 10 ? '0' : '').'%a %H %I';
```

The difference between `d` and `days`: for difference of 35 days you'll get value 35 in `$interval->days`, but only 5 in `$interval->d`, because the remaining 30 days end up in `$interval->m`.